# How would one Find the image of a function, given the domain/co-domain

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Was recently working on a problem involving the following.

**Let $$f(x)= \frac{3x-1}{x+2}$$
We can consider this formula as defining a function with co-domain R. However, the expression does not make sense for all x∈R, so the domain of f is not R.

(a) What is the maximal subset D⊆R for which this expression defines a function f:D→R?

(b) Let f:D→R be the function given by $f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x+2}$, where D is the set in (a).

Find the range (or image) of f. Prove your claim.

I understand that my domain is D here and my co domain is R, but how would I apply this to find my image.

Comment: You know what letter stands for the domain, namely D. But the question is asking for you to actually state explicitly what the set D is. For the image of this type function, set the formula equal to some letter like c. Then try to find x in terms of c. There will be one value of c that leads to there being no possible x. That's the only thing *not* in the image.

Comment: I follow the first half of your explanation, but not the rest. Are you implying that I would have to set \frac{3x-1}{x+2} = a variable like c? Then solve for x? 
Also one thing to note here is that we can't use calculas for solving this question, I think thats why its giving me some trouble as well.

Comment: You interpreted what coffeemath said correctly.  Try it.  You should your attempt to the question if you would like further feedback.

Comment: I solved for x liked you guys mentioned, and got a final answer of -2y-1 / y-3. So now what, is this my image?